# "Немерено" или "немеряно"?

Tags: орфография

"Немер**е**но" или "немер**я**но"? Мне в письме в газету вообще встретилось "не меряно" (в значении "очень много"). Как же все-таки правильно?

Comment: В Нацкорпусе разных вариантов немерено: Угля жрала она этим брюхом **немеряно**.[Дина Рубина. Окна (2011)]. Кошек я там перепробовал ― **не меряно**![Владимир Кунин. Кыся (1998-2000)]. Однако Ямнинов заупрямился: времени потратил месяцев восемь, сил ― **не мерено**, а все же добился, чего хотел[Андрей Волос. Дом у реки // «Новый Мир», 1998]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К своему удивлению, нашла в орфографическом словаре слово **немерЕно** в значении 'очень много'. Образовано оно от глагола *мерИть* (*мерЯть* - разговорное).

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, всё зависит от глаголов: мерить или измерять. Мы мерим наше имущество количеством: у нас дома всякого добра **немерено**.
Мы измеряем, например, высоту деревьев в саду. Но одно осталось **немеряно**.

Comment: Если говорить об измерениях, то дерево не измерено, или не мерено, или не меряно (во всех случаях раздельно) Пример: Барин, бывало, придет из собрания через край хлебнувши, сам себя не видит, В карты ему случаем пофартит, червонцы из кармана на стол брякнут, ― не считано, не меряно. [Саша Черный. Солдатские сказки/ Катись горошком (1932)] – М_Г 5 минут назад    править

Comment: Да, видимо потому, что в данном случае это не будет наречием